# How do I redirect with .htaccess without changing the URL that was typed in?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain, wildcard

Currently I have `[any_name].example.com` redirecting to `example.com/?id=[any_name]`

This is my .htaccess code for doing that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://example.com/?id=%1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I change my .htaccess so that `foo.example.com` redirects to `example.com/?id=foo` but still shows `foo.example.com` in the browser's address bar?

Comment: Are `foo.example.com` and `example.com` hosted on the same server with the same document root folder?

Comment: Yes, I am using a wildcard (*.example.com) which points to the same root folder as example.com

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `R` flag, or if you include the protocol/domain (e.g. `http://example.com`, mod_rewrite will redirect the browser instead of internally rewrite the request. Redirecting the browser causes the browser to load the new URL, which changes the URL in the address bar. You want to remove those so that you have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?id=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This solution is no longer changing the shown URL, but I am now getting a "500 Internal Server Error" page for any subdomain I type in.

Comment: This is almost working properly now. It is doing the internal redirect however the GET variable is not appending the subdomain name. `foo.example.com` internally redirects to `foo.example.com/?id=`, as if the `%1` does not exist.

Comment: @ClaytonKirlew try moving the query string condition to the top, I didn't think it would make a difference but apparently it does.